# Update Account fields based on its related Contract

Tags: apex, process-builder, lightning-flow-builder

I built a Flow (Record-Triggered Flow) in Salesforce Flow Builder that updates the fields *Contract Start Date*, *Contract End Date*, *Renewal Date* and *Contract Length (Months)* in the Account page.

To update those fields, the flow must take the values from the fields *Contract Start Date*, *Contract End Date*, *Next Renewal Date* and *Contract Term (months)* in the most recent Activated Contract related to the Account.

It works well when a new contract is created, however if the Account already has a Contract, the fields in the Account page don't update (i.e. the fields don't update with historical data).

Please, could you help know why does it happen?

I already tried with a AutoLaunch Flow and Process Builder, but they also didn't work.

Thank you,

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: welcome to SFSE; please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. In your case, you should use [edit] and include screenshots of the flow - which object is the target object, and the relevant elements

Comment: You can enable debug logs for your user record and check the logs after you finish the test. This should give you the actual error received.

Comment: Hello, @cropredy, I added more details and the screenshots as you requested. If more information is needed, please, tell me;

Comment: @AsifK, I will also try to do as you mentioned.